# Is it possible to decrypt a string given part of the original string

Tags: security, encryption

Suppose I have an encrypted string of bytes. "T37mQkZosCsrcbqf/rvSWbd67qH3sXMggKdVd8fzMdg="

Suppose I know that somewhere in the original plain text string I know there is a string of numbers in ascii: "1234567"

Is is realistically possible to figure out the encryption key, or the rest of the string with just this information?

Comment: What is the origin of this question? Is it some CTF?

Comment: Just curiosity :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the encryption mechanism is not completely broken, having partial knowledge about the plaintext does not help figure out the rest of the plaintext. A property of an encryption mechanism is [ciphertext indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability) under chosen plaintext attacks (IND-CPA) and under chosen ciphertext attacks (IND-CCA).

In plain English, a consequence of this is that if you have two guesses for the plaintext, and you're given a corresponding ciphertext for each plaintext, you can't yell which ciphertext matches each ciphertext. So, for example, even if you know that the plaintext is either `1234567a` or `1234567b`, there's no way to tell which one it is.

A further consequence is that even if you know many plaintext-ciphertext pairs, you still can't figure out the encryption key, since otherwise you'd be able to decrypt additional ciphertexts.

The only thing for which you can have partial information is the length of the plaintext. Since the ciphertext is 32 bytes long, unless the encoding is extremely bizarre, the plaintext would have to be 16 bytes or less (assuming a modern cipher with a 16-byte IV/nonce — even with some broken scheme such as ECB, it would have to be 32 bytes or less).

P.S. If the string is actually a [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) rather than a ciphertext, it's possible to find the original input, but only by brute force, trying all plausible guesses until you find the right one.

Answer (score -1):

Before having to figure out the encryption key, you would have to figure out the cryptosystem, which could be anything.

Also, be aware that many modern cryptosystems use a different key for encrypting (public key) and decrypting (private key).

Comment: Neither of this is relevant. Knowing the cryptosystem wouldn't help, unless it's some hopelessly broken amateur or antique thing. Whether the encryption scheme is symmetric or asymmetric doesn't change anything here.

Comment: OP talked about "figure out the encryption key". I just wanted to point out that knowing the key without the cryptosystem doesn't help; neither does it if it is a public key.